# Using Jsoup to extract single value from page source

Tags: java, selenium, jsoup

I need to extract just a single value from a web page. This value is a random number which is generated each time the page is visited. I won't post the full page source but the string that contains the value is:

```
            <span class="label label-info pull-right">Expecting 937117</span>
```

The "937117" is the value I'm after here. Thanks

Update

Here is what I've got so far:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.mywebsite.com).get();
    Elements value = doc.select("*what do I put in here?*");

    System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is described clearly in following snippet. I had created a HTML file with a similar SPAN tag inside. Use Document.select() to select elements with specific class name that you want.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sourceDir = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test.html";
    test(sourceDir);
}

private static void test(String htmlFile) {
    File input = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Elements classEles = null;

    try {
        input = new File(htmlFile);
        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "ASCII", "");
        doc.outputSettings().charset("ASCII");
        doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.base);

        /** Find all SPAN element with matched CLASS name **/
        classEles = doc.select("span.label.label-info.pull-right");

        if (classEles.size() > 0) {
            String number = classEles.get(0).text();
            System.out.println("number: " + number);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No SPAN element found with class label label-info pull-right.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you not use javascript regular expression syntax?  If you know the element you are interested in, extract it as a string $stuff from jsoup, then just do 
$stuff.match( /Expecting (\d*)/ )[1]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but I don't understand what you're saying? Can you write up a couple of lines of code to explain please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void yourMethod() {

          try {
                Document doc = connect("http://google.com").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
                Elements value = doc.select("span.label label-info pull-right");

              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }
```